# Facebook and Parse Login Issues

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm following the instructions for integrating Parse and Facebook from the following website:

I start by creating an App per Facebook's instructions. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/
I've configured the plist per facebook's settings.

Then I move to Parse:
I've started first configuring xCode with the following build libraries:
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing 
and then do the custom commands for integrating Facebook with Parse in Swift
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS

No matter what I do, I receive the following error from Xcode on compile:

has anyone seen this?

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFDateFormatter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Are there any easy fixes?

My Bridge-Header has the following files:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

Help!!  It is beyond frustrating and I can't seem to find the issue... 
I've updated

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your plist file to your question?

Comment: the problem fixed itself when I downloaded parse sdk 1.6.3 and upgraded from 1.6.2.  I don't know what the issues were but they are now resolved after I follow the same install steps.